# How do I make image move in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to make the images move but i keep getting an error for `value` saying it's not defined. I'm not sure if i'm even doing this correct can someone just make this thing work please!!

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
           window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
           window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
           window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
           window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
           function(callback) {
               window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
           };
    })();

    var blueCar = new Image();
    var redCar = new Image();

    // images
    function image(){
        blueCar.src = "http://worldartsme.com/images/car-top-view-clipart-1.jpg";
        redCar.src = "http://images.clipartpanda.com/car-clipart-top-view-free-vector-red-racing-car-top-view_099252_Red_racing_car_top_view.png";

    }

    window.onload = function draw(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

        // finish line
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(1020, 150);
        ctx.lineTo(1020, 0);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFEF0E";
        ctx.stroke();

        //blue car
        ctx.save();
        if (blueCar.complete) {
            ctx.drawImage(blueCar, 10, 10, 100, 60);
        }

        // red car
        if (redCar.complete) {
            ctx.drawImage(redCar, 10, 80, 100, 60);
        }
    }

    //animate on click
    document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('click', function animate(lastTime, redCar, blueCar, runAnimation, canvas, ctx) {
        if (runAnimation.value) {
            // update
            var time = (new Date()).getTime();
            var timeDiff = time - lastTime;

            var redSpeed = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1);
            var blueSpeed = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1);
            var linearDistEachFrameRed = redSpeed * timeDiff / 1000;
            var linearDistEachFrameBlue = blueSpeed * timeDiff / 1000;
            var currentX = redCar.x;
            var currentZ = blueCar.x;

            if (currentX < canvas.width - redCar.width - redCar.borderWidth / 2) {
                var newX = currentX + linearDistEachFrameRed;
                redCar.x = newX;
            }

            if (currentZ < canvas.width - blueCar.width - blueCar.borderWidth / 2) {
                var newZ = currentZ + linearDistEachFrameBlue;
                blueCar.x = newZ;
            }

            //clear
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            image();

            requestAnimFrame(function() {
                animate(time, redCar, blueCar, runAnimation, canvas, ctx);
            });
        }

        var runAnimation = {
            value: false
        };
    });
    image();
```

Comment: You are trying to use `runAnimation` before you define it. It also seems if you move it before your `if-statement` you never change the value or will be redefining it, and hence never be `true`.

Comment: You're also defining a window.requestAnimFrame function, and then calling requestAnimationFrame later. You're also requesting an animation frame before you've done any drawing operations. You should do your updating and drawing first, then request a fresh animation frame. Update, draw, request new frame, rinse, repeat :)

Comment: SO is not a place where people will just "make it work" for you

Comment: @Pamblam. Actually, helping with a problem relating to the questioner's own specific code is(!) one of the things we do on SO. :-)

Comment: @Spencer which `if statement` are you referring to?

Comment: @ManoDestra is it all in seperate functions?

Comment: What you've done above regarding requestAnimFrame is fine, as such, but I'd probably just store it in a variable myself and call it when I need it. E.g. `var raf = <what you have above to get requestAnimationFrame>;`. Then, I'd simply call `raf(callback);` as required. And, yes, use seperate functions for each thing. Have an update() function, a draw() function and a loop() function that calls both, then calls itself via `raf(loop)`, or whatever you choose to call it.

Comment: @ManoDestra thanks i'll give that a try

Comment: The specific error you're getting is because you're trying to access the runAnimation object before it is defined. Move the definition of runAnimation to the top of your script.

Comment: @ManoDestra has given you a nice demo of a race around a circular track and I've refactored the code in your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242582/animating-images-with-javascript) to demo your race game. Good luck with your project! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Thought I'd throw this out to you as an example of how to animate a car on a canvas. I took the blue car from your example above and simply move it in an oval without any rotation. You could easily implement the rotation of the car via [ctx.translate()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_translate.asp) and [ctx.rotate()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_rotate.asp) methods.

You can see that I am loading the image asset first and only starting my animation when the asset has loaded. Then, the loop is called, which calls draw and update, passing them the ticks and difference, to allow for smooth movement calculations inside those methods.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image Animation Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            const BLUE_URL = "http://worldartsme.com/images/car-top-view-clipart-1.jpg";
            const DESIRED_ROTATION_SPEED = Math.PI / 2;

            var raf;
            var blueCar;
            var ctx;
            var lastTick = 0;
            var position = { x:0, y:0, angle:0 };
            var center = { x:0, y:0 };

            function getRaf() {
                return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                    window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
                    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    function(callback) {
                        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                    };
            }

            function clearContext(fillColor) {
                ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
            }

            function update(gameTime) {
                position.angle += (gameTime.diff / 1000) * DESIRED_ROTATION_SPEED;
                if (position.angle > (Math.PI * 2)) {
                    position.angle -= Math.PI * 2;
                }

                position.x = center.x + (Math.cos(position.angle) * 180);
                position.y = center.y + (Math.sin(position.angle) * 140);
            }

            function draw(gameTime) {
                clearContext('#101010');
                var drawHeight = 100;
                var drawWidth = drawHeight * blueCar.width / blueCar.height;
                ctx.drawImage(blueCar, 0, 0, blueCar.width, blueCar.height, position.x - (drawWidth / 2), position.y - (drawHeight / 2), drawWidth, drawHeight);
            }

            function loop(tick) {
                var diff = tick - lastTick;
                lastTick = tick;
                var gameTime = { tick:tick, lastTick:lastTick, diff:diff };
                update(gameTime);
                draw(gameTime);
                raf(loop);
            }

            function init(event) {
                console.log(BLUE_URL);
                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                canvas.width = 800;
                canvas.height = 600;
                center.x = canvas.width / 2;
                center.y = canvas.height / 2;
                position.x = center.x;
                position.y = center.y;
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                raf = getRaf();
                blueCar = new Image();
                blueCar.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
                    startAnimation();
                }, false);
                blueCar.src = BLUE_URL;
            }

            function startAnimation() {
                raf(loop);
            }

            window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"><h1>Canvas not supported</h1></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the demo but i still don't understand what im doing.

Comment: It will come. Work your way through the code. Window loads, calls init. Init loads the blue car image. Once that has loaded fully, startAnimation is called. This then kicks off loop, which updates, draws, then calls itself again. Any questions, just ask :)